# On code clarity and functionality

Tags: objective-c

The following 2 methods are identical in terms of what they do. I wonder which of the following is preferred and why?

This looks cleaner from readability stand point, however i don't like the `decks.playerDeck` construct

```
-(void) playerMovedWithCard:(Card*) card {
    [decks removeCard:card fromDeck:decks.playerDeck];
    [decks addCard:card toDeck:decks.inplayDeck];
}
```

Definitely simpler, however the idea that `card` is removed or added seems to be lost (thinking of reader of the code)

```
-(void) playerMovedWithCard:(Card*) card {
    [decks.playerDeck removeObject:card];
    [decks.inplayDeck addObject:card];
}
```

I am leaning towards the first implementation, as in future the task of `removeCard` may be more involved then simply removing an object.

What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first way is slightly easier to read, because your `decks` serves as a more meaningful object. However, passing `decks.playerDeck` and `decks.inplayDeck` is not ideal: `removeFromInPlayDeck:` and `addToPlayerDeck:` would be slightly better.

There is a definite advantage to the first way of doing it, though: you could add a `moveCardFromDeck:toDeck:` method to the class of your `deck` object, avoiding the need to pass the same `card` twice to two different methods.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to even isolate the functionality of the `decks` object and remove any reference of `decks.playerDeck` and `decks.inplayDeck` from `playerMovedWithCard`. This way, you can change the class of `decks` without having to change any code in `playerMovedWithCard`.

For example:

```
- (void)playerMovedWithCard:(Card*)card
{
    [decks moveToPlayerDeckTheCard:card];
    // OR [decks moveToInPlayDeckTheCard:card];
}
```

This way, `playerMovedWithCard` is unaware of how cards are stored or even what happens when a card is moved.

You can change that according to what your app actually does, but the idea is to minimize any coupling between classes.